# file upload download php

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a script for file upload to  a MySQL db. 
I get an error saying :
`Notice: Undefined variable: code in C:\wamp\www\application\letters.php on line 82`
This is the word code which is in **. Anyone that can spot the mistake please let me know.

```
if ($name)
    if ($title && $description)
        {       
            $date = date("d m Y");
            $charset ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

            //length of value to generate
            $length = 15;

            //create variable and run through and randomly select fromcharset.
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++)
            {   
                //position to start at. rand function.
                $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
                $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);

                //append onto code
                **$code .= $tmp;**
            }
            //checking for existence of code which is generated. 
            $query= mysql_query("SELECT code FROM letter_details WHERE code = '$code'");

            //if code is found
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            // if that code exists, generate code again
            while ($numrows != 0)
            {
                for ($i=0; $i <= $length; $i++)
                {
                    //position to start at. rand function.
                    $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
                    $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);

                    //append onto code
                    $code .=$tmp;
                }

                //checking for existence of code which is generated.
                $query= mysql_query("SELECT code FROM letter_details WHERE code = '$code'");

                //if code is found
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            }

            //create directory
            mkdir("files/$code");

            //put file into it
            move_uploaded_file($tmpname, "files/$code/"."$name".$ext);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO letter_details VALUES ('$letter_id', $title','$code','$description','$student_info_id', '$staff_info_id', '$date')");
            echo "Your file '$title' was Succesfully uploaded.<br><br><a href='download.php?file=$code'>Download</a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define `$code` before adding more into to it  by `$code .= ''`  (put `$code = '';` before loop)

Comment: @BlueDolphin Try adding or die(mysql_error()); for your insert query | AND use mysqli instead mysql!

Comment: thats the error I got after adding in the or die bit....... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','SZkFQl6dQzQtyp6z','sdfsd','AD202010', 'YR202010051', '07 04 2013')' at line

Comment: as I sayed you have to use mysqli and prepare... But try adding $value = addslashes($value); for each variable in that query!

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing a ' before $title. I just wasted nearly 2 hrs figuring that out. Thanks to you though. You got me to that by adding in the MySQL_error thing.

Comment: Oh okay, no problem, but checkout mysqli!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `$code='';` outside the `for` loop.Variables are to be declared in such cases,ie concatenation operation, before they are used.

Comment: what did u mean by upload to database?also if file upload is the issue,check destination folder permissions.Make sure it is writable to www-data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a variable outside a `for` loop you must define it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is notice which warns you regarding undefined variables.

The execution of program does not affect by notice. 
To fix this you can initialize the $code variable somewhere in the starting of the script like `$code = '';`

Comment: Yes, thankyou. It gets rid of error but doesn't upload file. I DO not see why the file will not be then added to the database table?

Comment: I have added another answer for your query of uploading files. Please look. You can also upvote me if my answer really help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet of code you must use in your script for uploading files:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

Check and see if it works for you.

Comment: thankyou for that but ive figured it out and it working fine.

Comment: Glad to know... Share what you have figured so others can get help.